# .NET Core Entity Framework issue connecting to SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, console-application

In my console app, I connect to SQL Server 2014. I am able to fetch data and do what I need to do. Now, we changed to SQL Server 2019 on a different server. I we changed the connection string and the connection no longer works. There is no error returned... It just hangs there and eventually stops.

The connection string we have specified like so:

```
Server=DBDEVDB,1633;Database=DB_DEV;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

However, when I used the designer tool to scaffold the database, I used this same connection string and it works.

I cannot seem to figure out why the console app worked before but no longer works after updating the connection string when that same connection string works in the designer tool.

These are the specified dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.6"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.6" />
```

Any and all thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code. There's no incompatibility between EF Core 3.1 and Sql Server 2019

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even though the code has not changed and it used to work when connecting to the 2014 SS instance?

Comment: Do you really use port 1633? Is this a typo perhaps? In that case any attempt to connect would timeout and throw an exception. If your program swallows exceptions it will appear as if it's just stopping. If you use logging you'll see an exception in the logs

Comment: `even though the code has not changed` this means the problem is in your environment, not the library or the server. Thousands of developers use both

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I figured that to be true. Our SAs say it is exactly the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it is 1633.... The same conn str in the designer tool works.

Comment: EF Core doesn't have a designer and the default SQL Server port is 1433. Do you mean SSMS perhaps? Or something else? Again, post your code. You'd get an exception after a while if EF Core was unable to open a connection. If you don't it means your own code is swallowing exceptions. Add proper exception handling and logging and log the *entire* exception string produced by `Exception.ToString()`.